# Comparar com data anterior no oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Olá,

Preciso verificar quais foram as compras realizadas nos últimos 7 dias

```
select * from carros car  where to_date(to_char(to_date(car.datacompra,'yyyymmdd'),'dd-mm-yyyy')) = trunc(sysdate - 7)
```

me retorna o seguinte erro:

`ORA-01840: valor de entrada não é longo o suficiente para formato de data`

Obrigado

Comment: Qual o tipo do campo `datacompra` ?

Comment: é number... yyyymmdd mas é number

Comment: testei aqui e deu certo.. qual o tamanho do campo ?

Comment: o tamanho do campo é `number(8,0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O to_date espera receber um char, se o seu campo for do tipo Number, então você precisa fazer o primeiro o parse de number para char.

```
select * from carros car  where to_date(to_char(to_date(to_char(car.datacompra),'yyyymmdd'),'dd-mm-yyyy')) = trunc(sysdate - 7)
```

[Fonte : Documentação do TO_DATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm)

Edição 1

Minha primeira proposta de correção não estava adequada, acho que a esta query irá atender melhor suas necessidades:

```
select * from carros car where to_date(LPAD(to_char(car.datacompra), 8,'0'),'yyyymmdd')= trunc(sysdate - 7)
```

Removi algumas transformações, e adicionei o LPAD, para garantir que o to_date vai funcionar, evitando que o erro ocorra.

[Documentação LPAD](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2017.htm)

Comment: Obrigado.. mas aparece o mesmo erro

Comment: novato, qual o resultado disso para você:
select * from carros car  
where car.datacompra between trunc(sysdate - 7) and sysdate+1

Comment: No meu caso tenho que converter para `date` porque meu tipo de dados é number... mas ocorre o mesmo erro

Comment: Você consegue executar um select para verificar se existem valores em datacompra com menos de 8 caracteres?

Comment: Você pode tentar executar o seguinte select, o LPAD vai garantir que você terá uma string com 8 caracteres, e em teoria deve resolver o erro, mas isso não vai garantir a integridade do resultado.                  select * from carros car  where to_date(LPAD(to_char(car.datacompra), 8,'0'),'yyyymmdd')= trunc(sysdate - 7)

Answer (score 0):

E se fizer simplismente:

```
SELECT *
  FROM carros car
 WHERE TO_DATE(car.datacompra,'YYYY-MM-DD') =
       TRUNC(SYSDATE-7)
```

Comment: Obrigado...Mesmo erro....

Comment: Quantos registros tem na tabela?

Comment: tem 480 registros

Comment: Eu acho que deve ter registro no formato errado.... ordene e verifique pra gente? Faz no select a clausula do where

Comment: isso mesmo.... registro com com o campo não preenchido adequadamente